# Failed to find style 'chipIconSize' in current theme

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio

I wished to make floating label type of edit text. So I added this under dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

Now, I am getting this error under Render Problem:

```
Render Problem    
Failed to find style 'chipIconSize' in current theme
```

The above error is shown in the xml preview.

This is the dependency section in build gradle(module app) :

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'

//    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'


implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
}
```

The logcat shows the following error and warning under Java compiler:

```
The app gradle file must have a dependency on com.google.firebase:firebase-core for Firebase services to work as intended.  

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
```

How can I resolve the error?

Answer (score 0):

> The app gradle file must have a dependency on
>   `com.google.firebase:firebase-core` for Firebase services to work as
>   intended.

Add :

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
```

To your `build.gradle` dependencies.

For the :

> Failed to find style '`chipIconSize`' in current theme

It seems liek you'll need to add:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

To support that attribute from material design or simply, remove it.

**Check this link:** https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started/

Comment: I am still getting an error:  java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details.

Comment: Check the build errors-logss and it will show what’s the other issue. **check logs for details**